# Let $X\in\mathbb{A}^n$ be a variety, $U\in X$ open, $f\in A(X)$, $f(x)=0\ \forall\ x\in U$, then $f=0$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know that an analogous statement holds true in complex analysis, but I don't know how to prove the statement here. I know that $U$ is dense in $X$, and $f:X\to\mathbb{A}^1$ defines a continuous mapping, and the usual theorem in topology is that for topological spaces $X$, $Y$, with $Y$ Hausdorff, given $U\in X$ a dense set, and $f,g:X\to Y$ continuous s.t. $f|_U=g|_U$, then $f=g$ on all of $X$. However, $\mathbb{A}^1$ is not Hausdorff, so this particular approach doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The correct analogue of the Hausdorff property is [separatedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_algebraic_geometry). In this case: say I have regular functions $f,g$ on $X$. Define a morphism $\gamma\colon X \to \mathbb A^2$ by $x \mapsto (f(x), 0)$. Show that the "diagonal" $\{(a,a)\}$ in $\mathbb A^2$ is closed. Now $\gamma(U)$ is contained in the diagonal and $U$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: @Surb In American academia at least, variety usually means algebraic variety with the Zariski topology, and manifold is reserved for spaces that are locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @Callus: I ignored that. Thank you for this information :-)

Comment: I ended up proving this using the closed-set characterization of irreducible spaces, and by looking at the zero set of f.

Comment: That's good! As you can see I wavered between proving the special case and proving it for a general $f,g\colon X \to Y$ until my five minutes of editing were up. The point is that if a dense open set maps into a closed set then the whole space has to map into that closed set. In your situation the target closed set is just a point, but more general things (diagonals, graphs of functions) come up.

Comment: Could you explain the generalization to separateness in more detail? I've heard the word before, but I don't quite understand how this statement would be proved using it.